# Non interrupted code running via Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Im familiar with the fact that we as developers need to add a check for interrupts in our code when we write something that might run async via threads.

The following example shows the wrong case, when there is no check for interrupt in the runnable and therefore even if I got timeout exception on the main thread, the child thread keep running the task :

```
 public void myTest() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                log.info("test");
                Thread.sleep(40);
            }
        });
        try {
            future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread.sleep(500);
        log.info("done");
```

output :

```
test
test
test
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at myFile.myTest(MyFile.java:102)
test
test
test
test
done
```

By adding `future.cancel(true)` I got an unexpected behavior. According to what I understood, the cancel(boolean) method wont stop the task, if the task is already running, it might only interrupt it and thats all.

The code :

```
 public void myTest() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                log.info("test");
                Thread.sleep(40);
            }
        });
        try {
            future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            boolean value = future.cancel(true);
            log.info(""+value);
        }

        Thread.sleep(500);
        log.info("done");
```

The output :

```
test
test
test
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at myFile.myTest(MyFile.java:102)
true
done
```

So why by adding the future.cancel(true) the runnable stopped running ? I expected that during the 500 mili seconds that the main thread sleeps, I will see more test prints like I saw in the previous example.

Comment: Does I understand correctly, that you want your thread to be interrupted? Or whole code actually?

Comment: I'm trying to understand, why in my seconds example, the thread that runs the runnable, stopped running it. The goal is to understand what happened there..

Answer (score 0):

When you call `future.cancel(true)`, it will try to interrupt your executor thread. Executor thread will receive `InterruptedException` and die. That's where your `FutureTask` stops executing.

Comment: by sending an interrupt, you just change a boolean variable in the shared memory of that thread. Am I wrong here? If my runnable dont check if it was interrupted, how it will know ?

Comment: @JeyJ `Thread.sleep()` checks `interrupted` flag and if it is set it throws `InterruptedException` and clears the flag.

Comment: So If I remove the Thread.sleep() then it means that the thread will keep running right ?

Comment: @JeyJ yes, if you will remove `Thread.sleep()` your executor thread will not interrupt and `future.cancel(true)` will block.